# Avoiding Excel's Scientific Notation Rounding when Parsing with Pandas

Tags: python, parsing, pandas, import-from-excel

I have an excel file produced automatically with occasional very large numbers like `135061808695`.  In the excel file when you click on the cell it shows the full number `135061808695` however visually with the automatic "General" format the number appears as `1.35063E+11`.

When I use `ExcelFile` in Pandas the it pulls the value in scientific notation `1.350618e+11` instead of the full `135061808695`.  Is there any way to get Pandas to pull the full value without going in an messing with the excel file?

Comment: A (very) brief glance at the API suggests no, but, what's wrong with converting that scientific notation into a plain number with your own code?

Comment: Pandas might very well be pulling the "full value".  Just because it's displaying ```1.35063e+11``` doesn't mean there isn't more precision stored.   Print out with a format like ```15.0f``` to check.

Comment: Ahh... @JohnE you are correct. Its actually when I round trip and store the information down that I truly lose the precision though it appeared that I lost it earlier.  This was easy to fix.  If you want to write up a quick answer below I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pandas might very well be pulling the full value but not showing it in its default output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'x':[135061808695.] })

df.x
0    1.350618e+11  
Name: x, dtype: float64
```

Standard python format:

```
print "%15.0f" % df.x
135061808695
```

Or in pandas, convert to an integer type to get integer formatting:

```
df.x.astype(np.int64)

0    135061808695
Name: x, dtype: int64
```